# Best practices for using brackets in python expressions?

Tags: python

In Python, I have come to the realisation that when writing an expression, you can use brackets if you want to.  I'll give you an example:

```
while count > 10:
```

and

```
while (count > 10):
```

are both accepted by the compiler.

My question is what are the best practices when using brackets for expressions in python? i.e. **when should you use brackets in expressions?**

Comment: Only when you actually need to. If your expression is very complex, you can break it up into separate lines.

Comment: The reason I ask this is that I've been doing some C# lately and have started to use brackets more and now my code's getting inconsistent in use of brackets.  Now- if only python would use semicolons at the end of a line...

Comment: @N_Soong Strongly recommend you not use brackets just because you're used to it from another language. For one thing: write idiomatic Python because it's easier for other Python programmers to read. For another: often preferred styles emerge because it lends itself to design patterns that complement the language (expressive whitespace, in this case). Lastly: it's easier to make novice mistakes and mix up language features if you don't compartmentalize. If you're writing a `for` loop in Python and using parens, how much further is it to write `for (i=0; i<=10; i++)` which is NOT valid?

Comment: Write C# in C# and Python in Python. Don' try to be consistent between them. [A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Consistency).

Answer (score 5):

In the example you provide, brackets are not necessary. They clutter the code without any particular reason (that I can think of)

Some reasons to use brackets. Use brackets to:

**1) Improve code clarity**

`a * b + c` and `(a * b) + c` are equivalent, but the latter is clearer. The clarity aspect is even more evident when combining more complex code, like ternary operations.

**2) Override default order of operations**

`(a + b) * c` and `a + b * c` give different behavior.

Similarly, `X or Y and Z` is different from `(X or Y) and Z`.

Additionally, use of brackets can alleviate the need for the programmer to memorize the implicit [order of evaluation](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=459269&seqNum=11) by explicitly specifying the order.

Answer (score 1):

I always write brackets because I'm used to from languages that actually require them (C, Java...).  In my opinion it is also make the code easier to read.
However, brackets are only useful when actually needed, like computing compound expressions. There's no really other reason to add brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Only when it creates clarity of purpose.

```
if (condition_one and condition_two) or condition_three:
```

is okay, even though if you remove the parens it still works identically. It's not immediately obvious that `and` has a higher operator precedence than `or` (unless you've taken the time to memorize it).  Similarly no one faults you for doing that with the math:

```
(2 * 3) / 6
```

Obviously if you need to override operator precedence, brackets are the way to do it

```
(2 + 3) / 6 != 2 + 3 / 6
condition_one and (condition_two or condition_three) != \
    condition_one and condition_two or condition_three
```

However parens do add extra "noise" to the line that isn't necessary. Use them sparingly and only when actually necessary.

```
if (this) and (that) and (the_other):
```

should be

```
if all([this, that, the_other])
```

or at least

```
if this and that and the_other
```